# Git Rebase repeats conflicts from last Rebase

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-merge-conflict

Are there any common git usage mistakes or in general any reasons at all why a rebase would repeat the conflicts from the previous rebase if those conflicts had all been resolved in the previous rebase?
Furthermore, does rebase have a preference over how the conflict was resolved? e.g. does rebase want a strict choice between the two possible code snippets in the usual git conflict brackets within the code or is it just as fare to it to remove everything between the `>>>`,`<<<`?  I'm curious if removing both code choices to resolve the conflict will affect rebase's ability to resolve later conflicts properly.

Further elaboration:
I have a `master` branch and a `dev` branch.  The `dev` branch I've been working on the side for some time so the number of differing commits has grown quite large, in the 100s (I know...should `dev` into `master` more often).  `dev` branch itself has had several smaller feature branches cut from it and then merged back in, only ever having been cut, rebased, merged with `dev` branch and never `master` branch (that I can remember).  I rebased `dev` branch onto `master` branch 1 week ago.  I have since made a few more changes on `dev` branch and would like to rebase on `master` once again so I can prepare for a merge.  There has been a very small change to `master` branch in that 1 week window as well but the code files don't overlap.  However, when rebasing `dev` onto `master` I'm seeing the same set of conflicts being raised by git when I attempt the current rebase as compared to when I rebased one week ago.

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In general, it's normal - if you rebase like this rather than merging (eg. master into dev), then replaying the same patches will likely generate the same conflicts.

You can use [git rerere](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rerere) to remember your resolutions if this is a common problem in your workflow.